# Navigation Controller Button Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, augmented-reality

I got a button issue on my navigation controller. I am not sure if I ordered the navigation controller on the right place..

here is my problem: 
I want a button (home) on my viewController (the one with the "Choose source"), which navigates to my home view controller (the upper left one with the title "AR NOTE").

What I did:
I dragged a connection or line (dont know how to call the line, when you left click the button and then drag it to the other view controller) and connected the button with the home view controller.

What happened:
It worked, BUT there was a navigation bar on my home view controller as well which don't wanted to move away...

**Is there any way to navigate from the "Choose source" to my main View controller??

(btw, in the photo down here, I didn't connected the button with the viewcontroller "AR NOTE"/ "H0ME")[image]**

**in the second photo you can see what happens when I normally connect it**.................................................................................................................................................................

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you would not want to do what you did, because that will present a new Home VC. You probably want to go back to the Home VC which was originally presented, don't you?

You need to add an *unwind segue*.

In Home VC, add a method. This method will be called when the unwind segue is performed:

```
@IBAction unwindFromSources(segue: UIStoryBoardSegue) {

}
```

Then, control+drag the button to the "Exit" of the Home VC. Here's a picture if you don't know what I am referring to:

[image]

Now select the method you just wrote from the drop down. And you are done! You've just created an unwind segue to Home VC. iOS will intelligently figure out that to unwind to Home VC, it needs to dismiss the Choose Source VC and then the Navigation Controller.

Comment: It didn't works... here is what I did: 1. went to my homeVC.swift and entered your line. Then I went to my Main.SB and connected the Home-Btn with the exit of my HomeVC.

Comment: OHHHH YESSS IT WORKSSS (almost)... If I go back, I go back to my ARVC.. from there I can go back to my HOME